# COMBS2 script doesn't upload my ligand files for superposing on the fly

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

The script suppose to recieve serveral inputs:

ligand.txt, ligand.pdb, ligand.params and the all Gly and all Ala structures of the protien I am trying to design.

all of them exist in the directory I gave the path way to in the following code.

for some reason the ligand files don't load for my script

This is the error messege

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "run_design.py", line 97, in <module>
s.load_ligands(template, use_ligs_of_loaded_vdms_only=True,
File "/home/shifman/Combs2/combs2/design/_sample.py", line 2118, in load_ligands
raise Exception('No ligands were successfully loaded. Stopping the run.')
Exception: No ligands were successfully loaded. Stopping the run.
```

this is the snippet of the code:

```
s.load_ligands(template, use_ligs_of_loaded_vdms_only=True,
frac_non_hb_heavy_buried=0,
path_to_ligand_database='/home/shifman/astaxanthin/AXA/superpose_ligand/',
hull_tolerance=0,
run_parallel= True)
```

Comment: Your code doesnt mention ligand.txt